# Using Visual Flow - can I grab a product's unitprice in the converted currency?

Tags: visual-workflow, multi-currency

I am creating a 'Clone this opportunity in Org Currency' button. I need to 'switch' the opportunity, but have all products in the org's currency (currently USD).

We have Advanced Currency Management enabled.

How can I grab the originals opportunity line items (which maybe in non-USD) value ? as ACM is enabled, the amount I see is according to the close date of the opportunity.

But what I need, is to create a new opportunity, with the correct in USD.

[image: The current flow]

Edit:

I need to create a Zero-Sum oppty, that it's source is X-currency, and it's destination is Y[USD]-Currency, with different close dates.
In the screen capture, you can see what I get today, while using the said flow:
[image: Different USD total due to dated currencies]

---

A major step is to get the Converted amount of the lineitems (Opportunityproduct - in USD) of the original opportunity

The way to that is getting the correct exchange rate from the Dated Currency

---

Phase 2

With a new flow

[image]

I can create the new oppty, and add all it's products, in the standard pricebook, with USD. **Still, the issue of getting the correct 'Convertd' amount resides.**

In the specific example, I need that the total will be: 451.01 USD
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DatedConversionRate is a standard Salesforce table.

Created a record lookup to get the correct conversion rate
[image]

Then, using a formula, to calculate the correct unitprice
[image]

**Final flow:**
[image]